# Using a form multiple times where calling another forms subroutine

Tags: vb.net, forms, parameters

The title of this question was a little bit hard to word, but I'll explain it more clearly here.

I have an Orders form and 3 different Commission Rates forms, each of which have a button for opening a Customer Search form, a Supplier Search form and a Product Search form.

Let's use the Customer Search form (`frmCustomerSearch`) being opened from the Order form (`frmOrder`) as the example.

I've created a form for loading a list of all customers, whereby the user can either find the customer in the list, or search for their name, code or search by category.

The results are displayed in an `UltraWinGrid`, from the `Infragistics` suite.

When double clicking on a row to select that customer, `frmCustomerSearch` closes, and `frmOrder.addCustomerFromSearch` is called, where the selected customer code is passed into the subroutine, and then `frmOrder` will populate the customer information using that code.

This is working no problem, however, I then need to open the same `frmCustomerSearch` window from the 3 Commission Rates screens, so that again the user can select the customer they're adding to the commission rate.

I don't want to create a new customer, supplier and product search form for each window, but I'm struggling to work out how to use the same form for each.

Currently I've got `Dim fOrder As frmOrder` at the top of the class, followed by:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection, ByVal orderform As frmOrder)

  Try
    fOrder = orderform
    con = conn

    InitializeComponent()

  Catch ex As Exception
    errorLog(ex)

  End Try
End Sub
```

So, `frmOrder` is passed in as the `orderform` parameter, meaning that I can use the following code to populate the customer details in the order form when double clicking a customer.

```
If fOrder.IsHandleCreated = True Then
   fOrder.addCustomerFromSearch(cCode)
Else
   MsgBox("Order screen is no longer open, unable to add customer.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
End If
```

How can I change this code to enable me to pass in a different form as a parameter, then call the subroutine on that form to populate the customer?

I tried changing it to `Dim f As Form` and then again using `ByVal frm As Form` in `Public Sub New`, but then the subroutine of that form couldn't be called, because it had no idea which form to look for `f.addCustomerFromSearch` in.

Is this even possible? Hopefully it makes sense, it's a little confusing to explain though, so apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt656692.aspx):

> Reflection provides objects (of type [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.type.aspx)) that describe assemblies, modules and types. You can use reflection to dynamically create an instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, or get the type from an existing object and invoke its methods or access its fields and properties. If you are using attributes in your code, reflection enables you to access them. For more information, see [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/5x6cd29c.aspx).

What I would do is declare a `Private _form As Form` at the top. I would then create [Overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybxdk47f.aspx) for the `New` method like so:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection, ByVal orderform As frmOrder)

  Try
    _form = orderform
    con = conn

    InitializeComponent()

  Catch ex As Exception
    errorLog(ex)

  End Try
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection, ByVal customersearchform As frmCustomerSearch)

  Try
    _form = customersearchform
    con = conn

    InitializeComponent()

  Catch ex As Exception
    errorLog(ex)

  End Try
End Sub
```

Now that we have `_form` we can look at reflection:

```
Dim dynMethod As Reflection.MethodInfo = _form.[GetType]().GetMethod("addCustomerFromSearch")

If dynMethod IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim parameters() As Object = {cCode}

    dynMethod.Invoke(_form, parameters)
End If
```

This is assuming your `addCustomerFromSearch` method looks like this:

```
Public Sub addCustomerFromSearch(ByVal code As String)

End Sub
```